# Copy files from Jenkins server (Linux) to Windows 2003 Share location

Tags: windows, jenkins, file-transfer, windows-2003-webserver

I am trying to connect to a Windows 2003 server from Jenkins box (Linux).

Adding a Jenkins slave is kind of difficult as I am struggling to install Java version to work with the agent. I am also not able to get the exact steps to install ssh server for windows which might solve my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are trying to connect from LInux to windows you need to so an ssh from linux... and try this on windows https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server

Comment: The answer is in your question, use a network share to do what you want.

Comment: I was able to solve the connectivity issue using portable java and CIFS plugin. But still, I am unsure why CIFS plugin does not copy the folders and only copies the files from a base location.